# Gem/plugin to handle mailing in Ruby on rails 2.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rubygems

I'm searching for a new (and hopefully) easier way to send mails from ruby on rails. I want to use a html template ans pass some var into them like name, surname, email etc. I found the mail gem but i'm not sure if that one is the right pick. Does anybody has any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use postmarkapp (http://postmarkapp.com/) I have used it in my recent project and it works great!

http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-libs.html#rails-gem

Answer (score 0):

Use [ActionMailer](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html). It's built into rails and requires little to no configuration.

Comment: is there any particular reason why?

Comment: I don't like how the multipart emails are handled in rails 2.3.x with actionmailer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [PostageApp](http://www.postageapp.com/)!

It has a robust template system that automatically in-lines HTML and CSS, and you can pass variables through the API. Check out the documentation on how to integrate it into your Ruby apps.

(**Full Disclosure**: I am the Product Manager for PostageApp)